Schemathesis Job Failure on GitLab CI Pipeline
I have created a Spring Boot application with a GitLab CI pipeline that builds the Maven jar file, uses Schemathesis to test the API endpoints based on an OpenAPI specification, and deploys to Amazon EKS. However, the job responsible for running Schemathesis is failing.
To test the application, Schemathesis queries the live application, so I created a start-api job to run the application in .gitlab-ci.yml:
start-api:
  stage: test
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  script:
    - mvn spring-boot:run &
    - sleep 60
  tags:
    - aks

Then, I pull the latest Schemathesis Docker image (as per the documentation), and run the test command with an api-tests job:
api-tests:
  stage: test
  image:
    name: schemathesis/schemathesis:stable
    entrypoint: ['']
  needs:
    - job: start-api
  tags:
    - aks
  script:
    - sleep 30
    - st run ./api.yml --checks=all --report --base-url=http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/v3/

The start-api job passes successfully, but the api-tests job fails with the following run:
Running with gitlab-runner 16.10.0 (...)
  on gitlab-runner-(...), system ID: (...)
  feature flags: FF_KUBERNETES_HONOR_ENTRYPOINT:true
Resolving secrets
Preparing the "kubernetes" executor
Using Kubernetes namespace: helm-gitlabrunners
Using Kubernetes executor with image schemathesis/schemathesis:stable ...
Using attach strategy to execute scripts...
Preparing environment
Using FF_USE_POD_ACTIVE_DEADLINE_SECONDS, the Pod activeDeadlineSeconds will be set to the job timeout: 1h0m0s...
Waiting for pod helm-gitlabrunners/runner-(...) to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod helm-gitlabrunners/runner-(...) to be running, status is Pending
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
    ContainersNotReady: "containers with unready status: [build helper]"
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: setting up trapping scripts on emptyDir: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("build"). Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information

What could be causing this error? Any assistance is appreciated!

The issue you have is not schemathesis specific but rather general misunderstanding of gitlab ci. I hope my answer helps to resolve it.

first off all I'm not sure that the error is related to what you describe.
The error
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: setting up trapping scripts on emptyDir: unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("build"). Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
suggests that it was not able to setup the container. Probably it wasn't able to pull schemathesis/schemathesis:stable container.
Next, you use --base-url=http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/v3/ for accessing you app. But your api-tests job will not see start-api on 127.0.0.1. For the communication to be available on localhost you have to deploy everything in one job. For example you can pack the app into container and then run it as a service for the schemathesis job. It will look like this:
api-tests:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: my-app-in-container:some-tag-to-test
      alias: test-app
  image:
    name: schemathesis/schemathesis:stable
    entrypoint: ['']
  needs:
    - job: start-api
  tags:
    - aks
  script:
    - sleep 30
    - st run ./api.yml --checks=all --report --base-url=http://test-app:8081/api/v3/

both 127.0.0.1 and test-app are valid choices for the URL
Lastly, there is a general flaw with the approach of running app in one job and to test it in another job.

Gitlab doesn't promise that they will be executed in parallel. If you have available resources to start only one job now, it will run alone
The first job doesn't know when to stop, so it will probably run until you reach the job timeout, which is also not very good in the context of resource usage.
It might be complicated the correct URL to access the pod with the running app, and I'm not even sure the app's port will be exposed outside of the pod.

